# Datasets: Is there any public data-set for FAQ (Frequently asked questions) in different domains?

Tags: machine-learning, web-crawling, nlp

My thesis is about Analysis and Auto generation of FAQ in different domains. For conducting experiments, I need high volume of FAQs. That's the reason I am looking for a publicly available data-set containing FAQs in various domain (or even one specific domain).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (among others)

- The usenet FAQ archives http://www.allanswers.org/
- Game FAQs http://www.gamefaqs.com/
- Internet FAQs http://www.faqs.org/faqs/

Answer (score 3):

You can download FAQs from github, although they won't really be cross-domain...

- [Github Advanced Search](https://github.com/search/advanced)
- [Example of a simple query that returns some FAQs files](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=faq%20%20%20size%3A1000&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=) (will require some fine-tuning, of course)
- [Github Search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#rate-limit)
- [Developer libraries](https://developer.github.com/libraries/)

Answer (score 3):

What about StackOverflow's own dataset? https://archive.org/details/stackexchange